# Why am I getting "too many include files : depth = 1024"?

Tags: c++, include

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Express edition, and keep getting the following error:

`"Cascadedisplay.h(4) : fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024`.

Obviously I'm doing something very wrong with include files, but I just can't see what.

Basically, I have an interface class, `StackDisplay`, from which I want to derive `CascadeDisplay` in another file:

```
#if !defined __BASE_STACK_DISPLAY_H__
#define __BASE_STACK_DISPAY_H__

#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>
#include "CascadeDisplay.h"

namespace Sol
{
    class StackDisplay
    {
        public:
            virtual ~StackDisplay();
            static boost::shared_ptr<StackDisplay>
            make_cascade_display(boost::shared_ptr<int> csptr)
            {
                return boost::shared_ptr<StackDisplay>(new CascadeDisplay(csptr));
            }
    };
}
#endif
```

and then in CascadeDisplay.h:

```
#if !defined __CASCADE_DISPLAY_H__
#define __CASCADE_DISPAY_H__

#include "StackDisplay.h"
#include <boost\shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace Sol
{
    class CascadeDisplay: public StackDisplay
    {
        public:
            CascadeDisplay(boost::shared_ptr<int> csptr){};
    };
}

#endif
```

So what's up with that?

Comment: I would try to avoid having each header include the other.

Comment: I would remove that static function from the base. It doesn't belong there. It could be a free function (e.g in a namespace), declared in "CascadeDisplay.h". - Headers including each other simply won't work.

Comment: I believe it's likely that there's a design flaw here that goes deeper than your typo'd header guard.

Comment: @UncleBens, I used the static function in an attempt to emulate Scott Meyers in Item 31 of Effective C++. Its possible I've misunderstood where he's coming from however.

Comment: As a side note, you should rename your header guard defines. Identifiers containing double underscore *or* beginning with a single underscore followed by an upper-case character (or anything beginning with a single underscore in namespace scope (outside classes and functions) is reserved to the implementation. The compiler *probably* doesn't define `__CASCADE_DISPLAY_H__`, but it could, and it would be legal for it to do so. Using something like `CASCADE_DISPLAY_H_` instead would be guaranteed not to conflict with anything the compiler or standard library uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `#if !defined...` legit?  I always used `#ifndef`.

Either way, why does your "base" class require the reference to `CascadeDisplay`?  That doesn't seem right.  Consider replacing your call to create a new `CascadeDisplay` with a call to a pure virtual function in `StackDisplay` that your subclass must implement appropriately.

IE, something like (and forgive, I don't have a c++ compiler handy to check this):

```
namespace Sol
{
    class StackDisplay
    {
        public:
            virtual ~StackDisplay();
            boost::shared_ptr<StackDisplay>
            make_cascade_display(boost::shared_ptr<int> csptr)
            {
                return make_display(csptr);
            }

        protected:
            virtual boost::shared_ptr<StackDisplay> make_display(boost::shared_ptr<int> csptr) = 0;
    };

    class CascadeDisplay: public StackDisplay
    {
        public:
            CascadeDisplay(boost::shared_ptr<int> csptr){};

        protected:
            virtual boost::shared_ptr<StackDisplay> make_display(boost::shared_ptr<int> csptr)
            {
                return new CascadeDisplay(csptr);
            }
    };
}
```

I believe this solution is superior, in general, to the forward declaration because you're eliminating some tight coupling between your superclass and your subclass, and making a more generic interface besides.  This lets you eliminate the `#include` of CascadeDisplay.h in StackDisplay.h.

Comment: Greg, I have used your code and it compiles fine. I was using that reference to CascadeDisplay in the base class because of Item 31 in Effective C++. Scott Meyers did it, so I thought I would. Your solution is indeed superior however.

Comment: Having said that, your solution does not allow me to call `make_cascade_display()` on a `StackDisplay` pointer without making it a static function. If I do this, I get a complaint regarding the illegal call of the non-static `make_display()` from the static `make_cascade_display`.

Comment: Ah, I consider this to be part of the difficulty of conflating two roles in a single class.  In general, I consider the "creation" of an object to be different from the "use" of an object, and so I typically prefer to create a separate factory class rather than use a factory method-- Especially in C++.  A ghetto workaround to keep your method static might involve making a static settable property on StackDisplay that is a function pointer to the equivalent of the make_display method.

Answer (score 9):

```
#if !defined __CASCADE_DISPLAY_H__
#define __CASCADE_DISPAY_H__
```

Second line should be:

```
#define __CASCADE_DISPLAY_H__
```

Same with:

```
#if !defined __BASE_STACK_DISPLAY_H__
#define __BASE_STACK_DISPAY_H__
```

Also, names that contain a double-underscore are reserved for the implementation, you are not allowed to create such names in your own code. Same goes for names that begin with a single underscore and an uppercase letter.

Comment: @BeeBand: Use `#ifndef` to make typos like this visible. `#ifndef` is the same length as `#define`, so the macro names will be aligned, and you'll spot immediately that one is missing a character. :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in your guards

```
#if !defined __CASCADE_DISPLAY_H__     <--- here you have DISPLAY
#define __CASCADE_DISPAY_H__           <--- here you have DISPAY (no L!)
```

and yes, avoid double underscores in such names